# JSON + PHP: Display nested elements with a click of a button

Tags: php, json

I'm very curious if it is possible to display elements with a click of a button.

How my code looks like:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=3bd884bb0078f836a56f1464097fb71eac9d50ce";
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $object = json_decode($response, true);
    foreach ($object['data'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo "<input type='button' value='".$value['title']."'>"; 
    }
?>
```

It it showing the exact result I wanted. So whenever I add new elements, it will also display the new element in a button.

Result looks like:

[image: This is how the result looks like]

Each button has its own unique ID [1,2,3]
and each ID has its own information.

So I wanted to display more information of each button whenever you click it. Is it possible? If so, any idea how to start of?

Comment: For achieving this you would need some javascript. Either use some JS framework like JQuery or write vanilla JS.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check out JavaScript...

Comment: @mazedlx I found out a way how to do it while assigning an exact id value for each button but not dynamically. Can you give me an idea how to start?

Comment: show some code please :-)